# On mobile input type date does not display the saved value

Tags: html, date, mobile

I have a problem when I try to set a date input for the mobile version of my site.
I use:
`<input type="date" name="this_start_date" id="this_start_date" value="<%if this_start_date<>"" then %><%=this_start_date%><%else%><%=date()%><%end if%>">`

Unfortunately the value saved in database is not displayed.
and the input behave weird for different browsers, for example:

- on chrome I see "dd/mm/yyyy" on desktop but nothing on mobile.
- on FF I see the date on the desktop but nothing on mobile.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a warning on DevTools console?

Comment: Not something that i can see...no errors,
When i touch the field on mobile, the native calendar shows up and the current date displays inside the input field.